# skipping elements or filling elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if the below is possible to accomplish in python/pandas dataframes. Specifically, I am looking to first find an observation in my dataframe, ex: value = 1 and if that is the case I want to forward fill the next n rows in that column to 1 as well.

here is how my dataframe would look like

```
Index  Date      Open  High  Low  Close  Long
0      19970101  500   501   499  501.5  0
1      19970102  501.5 505   499  502.5  0
2      19970103  503   507   503  506.5  0
3      19970104  503   507   503  506.5  1 (first instance)
4      19970105  503   507   503  506.5  1 (change here)
5      19970106  503   507   503  506.5  0 (change here)
6      19970107  503   507   503  506.5  -1 (reset) 
7      19970108  503   507   503  506.5  0
8      19970109  503   507   503  506.5  1  (second instance)
```

so where Long = 1 (check index = 6) I want the following n - rows (suppose n = 2 and so index 7, 8 in column Long) to also be 1. This is irregardless if its already 1 or if its 0.
when Long = -1, we reset and look for the next first Long = 1
Long can only be 0, 1 or -1

Any help, documentation would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to vectorize this, but here is code that should work.

```
n = 2
fill_counter = 0
longs = []
for i, val in enumerate(df.Long):
    if val == 1 and not fill_counter:
        # First observed value of 1.
        fill_counter = n + 1
    if fill_counter:
        fill_counter -= 1
        longs.append(1)
        continue
    longs.append(val)
df['Long'] = longs

>>> df
       Date   Open  High  Low  Close  Long
0  19970101  500.0   501  499  501.5     0
1  19970102  501.5   505  499  502.5     0
2  19970103  503.0   507  503  506.5     0
3  19970104  503.0   507  503  506.5     1
4  19970105  503.0   507  503  506.5     1
5  19970106  503.0   507  503  506.5     1
6  19970107  503.0   507  503  506.5    -1
7  19970108  503.0   507  503  506.5     0
8  19970109  503.0   507  503  506.5     1
```